# C++ both input and output pipe to the external program

Tags: c++, process, pipe, system

I am trying to invoke external program with some input and retrieve the output from it within a program.

It will be look like;

> (some input) | (external program) | (retrieve output)

I first thought about using a `popen()` but it seems like, it is not possible because the **pipe is not bidirectional**.

Is there any easy way to handle this kind of stuff in **linux**?

I can try making a temp file but it will be great if it can be handled clearly without accessing the disk.

Any Solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On linux you can use [`pipe`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html) function: Open two new pipes, one for each direction, then create a child process using [`fork`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/fork), afterwards, you typically close the file descriptors not in use (read end on parent, write end on child of the pipe for parent sending to child and vice versa for the other pipe) and then start your application using [`execve`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) or one of its front ends.

If you [dup2](https://linux.die.net/man/2/dup) the pipes' file descriptors to the standard console file handles (`STDIN_FILENO`/`STDOUT_FILENO`; each process separately), you *should* even be able to use `std::cin`/`std::cout` for communicating with the other process (you might want to do so only for the child, as you might want to keep your console in parent). I have no tested this, though, so that's left to you.

When done, you'd yet [`wait` or `waitpid`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/wait) for your child process to terminate. Might look like similar to the following piece of code:

```
int pipeP2C[2], pipeC2P[2];
// (names: short for pipe for X (writing) to Y with P == parent, C == child)

if(pipe(pipeP2C) != 0 || pipe(pipeC2P) != 0)
{
    // error
    // TODO: appropriate handling
}
else
{
    int pid = fork();
    if(pid < 0)
    {
        // error
        // TODO: appropriate handling
    }
    else if(pid > 0)
    {
        // parent
        // close unused ends:
        close(pipeP2C[0]); // read end
        close(pipeC2P[1]); // write end

        // use pipes to communicate with child...

        int status;
        waitpid(pid, &status, 0);

        // cleanup or do whatever you want to do afterwards...
    }
    else
    {
        // child
        close(pipeP2C[1]); // write end
        close(pipeC2P[0]); // read end
        dup2(pipeP2C[0], STDIN_FILENO);
        dup2(pipeC2P[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
        // you should be able now to close the two remaining
        // pipe file desciptors as well as you dup'ed them already
        // (confirmed that it is working)
        close(pipeP2C[0]);
        close(pipeC2P[1]);

        execve(/*...*/); // won't return - but you should now be able to
                         // use stdin/stdout to communicate with parent
    }
}
```

Comment: so tldr; Bind the two pipes with the forked child process and execve that child process to the target external program?

Comment: The two pipe names are very confusing.

Comment: @PavanManjunath they should have been short for "**P**arent writing to(**2**) **C**hild" and vice versa...